# Covariance and correlation coefficient

Tags: python, numpy

I have two random variables and I need to calculate precisely some characteristics for them.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3052308/calculated-covariance-corr-coefficient-confirmation?noredirect=1#

I already did this in Java but I want to confirm my answers with at least one more tool.

Could anyone good at python / probability provide me with some guidance how I can calculate these 6 values in python? I guess it is really simple but I am not very confident in python.

I looked at the documentation of the numpy cov function but I have difficulty to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use the functions from `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

e_X = np.average(X_values, weights=X_weights)
e_Y = np.average(Y_values, weights=Y_weights)

varX = np.average((X_values-e_X)**2, weights=X_weights)
varY = np.average((Y_values-e_Y)**2, weights=Y_weights)

cov_XY = np.cov(X_values, Y_values)
corrcoef_XY = np.corrcoef(X_values, Y_values)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it today.

Comment: I should have given the joint distribution of X and Y. My question is not really valid.

Comment: @peter.petrov It depends. You can replace the variable names wih your variable names. If he results are the same as you posted on Statistics, it's fine. For the rest, I suggest you to learn some statistics, so you can verify the values.

Comment: Hm... But to define/calculate `cov` you need to have the joint distribution of the two variables, no?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53945334/calculate-marginal-distribution-from-joint-distribution-in-python  Here is the real thing. This is the joint distribution that I am given, I want to calculate the marginal of X and Y from it. I already figured out how to calculate the covariance and the correlation coefficient.